# App Store - Free app with externally paid for login - does this require revenue split with Apple?

Tags: ios-appstore, mac-appstore

I'm trying to get clarity on this, I believe I know this answer but would like validation that I am correct.

I am building app and which will be free on the App Store, but users will have to login to a privately paid for system to access it.

E.g. anyone can download the App, but to use it, will have to have a contract with my company and then be provided with the credentials to login.

My thought is that this is fine without the revenue split, as lots of other apps do similar things, e.g. Facebook, Banking Apps, etc.. and to me, it wouldn't make sense for them to rev share either.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine, providing there is no link within the app to your website to purchase access.